# Term-by-Term Differentiation and UNIFORM CONVERGENCE: True Relation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

For a series with  $\sum u_n'(x)$  not uniformly convergent, and
 If $f '(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n'(x) $
 where $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) $ and  $ f_n(x) $ $=u_1+u_2+ . . . +u_n$

Then the series $\sum u_n(x)$  can be differentiated term by term, is this condition true for any series?

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum_{k}f_k(x)=f(x)$, even if it's not uniformly convergent on $]a,b[$, it will be uniformly convergent on $[c,d]$ for all $a<c<d<b$. Therefore, if $\sum_{k}f_k'(x)=f'(x)$ on $]a,b[$, and $x\notin\{a,b\}$, then you can always differentiate $\sum_{k}f_k(x)$ term by term.

Comment: The doubt is both the series with $ f_n(x) = \frac {\log(1+n^4x^2)}{2n^2}$  and  the series with $ f_n(x)=\dfrac{nx}{1+n^2x^2} $ satisfies this condition.  But  series with  $ f_n(x)=\dfrac{nx}{1+n^2x^2} $ cannot be differntiated term by term at $x=0$ , WHY?

Comment: You need some additional conditions for locally uniform convergence of the series. Let $g \colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ a sufficiently smooth function with $\operatorname{supp} g = [0,1]$, and for $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ let $g_n(x) = g\bigl(n(n+1)x - \frac{1}{n}\bigr)$. Set $f_1 = g_1$ and $f_n = g_n - g_{n-1}$ for $n \geqslant 2$. Then $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty f_n(x) = 0$ for all $x$, and $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty f_n'(x) = 0$ for all $x$. But neither convergence is uniform on any neighbourhood of $0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a stronger version (uniformly integrability condition) of what you need:

If a sequence of  absolutely continuous functions {$f_n$} converges pointwise to some $f$  and if the sequence of  derivatives {$f_n’$}  converges almost everywhere to some  $g$ and if {$f_n’$} is uniformly integrable then $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} f_n’ = g= f’$ almost everywhere. Where the derivative of  $f$ is $f’$. If the convergence is pointwise and $ g $ is continuous then $ f'$ = $ g $ everywhere.

Proof : by FTC  $f_n(x) – f_n(a) = \int_a^x f_n’ dx$

By Vitali convergence theorem : $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}\int_a^x f_n’ dx = \int_a^x g dx$

Therefore $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}( f_n(x) – f_n(a))= \int_a^x g dx$

$f(x)-f(a) = \int_a^x g dx$

$f(x)’=g$ almost everywhere

If the convergence is pointwise and $ g $ is continuous then $ f'$ = $ g $ everywhere.

Comment: My doubt is both the series with $ f_n(x) = \frac {\log(1+n^4x^2)}{2n^2}$  and  the series with $ f_n(x)=\dfrac{nx}{1+n^2x^2} $ satisfies this condition.  But  series with  $ f_n(x)=\dfrac{nx}{1+n^2x^2} $ cannot be differntiated term by term at $x=0$ , WHY?

Comment: Have you proved uniform integrability of {$f_n$}?

Comment: I didn't see any problem. why did you say it cannot be differentaited term by term at x=0?